# Save spreadsheet ranges as CSV file function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a code in GAS (Google APP Script) and I'm in way over my head here.

This code, attached to a google docs spreadsheet is supposed to take a collection of ranges from different tabs and copy their values to a new CSV file. I've put together a script that looks functional (based on my limited experience with GAS) but when I run it I get this error:

> Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context.

Though I'm sure it's full of other errors that I don't know how to properly address.

Here's what I got:

```
// Function will run upon clicking assigned drawing object in spreadsheet
function exportData() {

  // Prompts the user for the file name
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var fileName = ui.prompt(
   'Export Project Data',
    'Save input values to new file?\n\nFile Name:',
   ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // if user clicks 'yes' to save
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {

    // Check that the file name entered wasn't empty
    if (fileName.length !== 0) {

      // Add the ".csv" extension to the file name
      fileName = fileName + ".csv";

      // Convert the range data to CSV format using the function defined below
      var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);

      // Create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the CSV data
      DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
      }

    // If given file name is empty display message
    else {
      Browser.msgBox("Error: Please enter a CSV file name.");
    }
  }

  // if user clicks 'no' to exit
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO) {}
}



// Function will run when called upon by another function
function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {

  // Define all the input ranges from the spreadsheet
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Project Info');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Manufactured Materials');
  var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Assembly Features');
  var sheet4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Add-On Materials');
  var sheet5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Decorative Pulls');
  var sheet6 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Häfele Hardware');
  var sheet7 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Häfele Lighting');
  var sheet8 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Rev-A-Shelf');
  var sheet9 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sidelines');
  var sheet10 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Other Products');
  var sheet11 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Non-Stock');
  var allRanges = [
    sheet1.getRange("C4:C10"),
    sheet1.getRange("E4:E10"),
    sheet1.getRange("G4:G10"),
    sheet1.getRange("C13:E19"),
    sheet1.getRange("E21:E24"),
    sheet1.getRange("A39:H50"),
    sheet2.getRange("C3:I3"),
    sheet2.getRange("C7:I8"),
    sheet2.getRange("C11:I12"),
    sheet2.getRange("C37:I37"),
    sheet2.getRange("C40:I40"),
    sheet2.getRange("C43:I43"),
    sheet2.getRange("C46:I48"),
    sheet2.getRange("C51:I53"),
    sheet2.getRange("C55:I57"),
    sheet2.getRange("C59:I61"),
    sheet2.getRange("C63:I63"),
    sheet2.getRange("C67:I67"),
    sheet2.getRange("B70:I74"),
    sheet3.getRange("C3:I7"),
    sheet3.getRange("C12:I13"),
    sheet3.getRange("C16:I18"),
    sheet3.getRange("C21:I23"),
    sheet3.getRange("C25:I27"),
    sheet3.getRange("C31:I38"),
    sheet3.getRange("C41:I41"),
    sheet4.getRange("C3:I4"),
    sheet4.getRange("C6:I6"),
    sheet4.getRange("C32:I37"),
    sheet4.getRange("C39:I40"),
    sheet4.getRange("C43:I48"),
    sheet4.getRange("C52:I54"),
    sheet4.getRange("C57:I57"),
    sheet4.getRange("C59:I61"),
    sheet4.getRange("C63:I65"),
    sheet4.getRange("C67:I68"),
    sheet4.getRange("C72:I72"),
    sheet4.getRange("C74:I77"),
    sheet4.getRange("C81:I83"),
    sheet4.getRange("C86:I88"),
    sheet4.getRange("C91:I95"),
    sheet5.getRange("A3:G50"),
    sheet6.getRange("A3:G150"),
    sheet7.getRange("A3:G120"),
    sheet8.getRange("A3:G50"),
    sheet9.getRange("A3:G50"),
    sheet10.getRange("A3:G30"),
    sheet11.getRange("B5:K14"),
    sheet11.getRange("B17:K26"),
    sheet11.getRange("B29:K38"),
    sheet11.getRange("B41:K50"),
    sheet11.getRange("B53:K62"),
    sheet11.getRange("B65:K74"),
    sheet11.getRange("B77:K86")
  ]

  // Get the values from the input ranges in the spreadsheet
  try {
    var csvFile = undefined;
    var data = sheet1.getValues(allRanges);

    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is attached to a spreadsheet, you need  `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` not DocumentApp

Comment: Putting "IMPORTANT" at the end of the title might give the impression that you expect someone to rush in and fix your problem.  No one has an obligation to work on the answer.

Comment: Well, I've changed my code so that 'DocumentApp.getUi()' is replaced by 'SpreadsheetApp.getUi()' and replaced 'response.getSelectedButton()' with 'fileName.getSelectedButton()'. Now I don't get any more errors but it still doesn't work. I get the filename dialog box to pop up, but nothing saves when I give a file name and click ok.